# Error on ng-view in Angular Js

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to implement Routing in Angular JS. Here is code-

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app="myApp">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#/about">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#/contact">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </header>

 <div ng-view>
    </div>
<form id="form1" ng-controller="EmpCtrl" ng-submit="save()">
//code
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Controller-

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
app.config(['$routeProvider',
        function ($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider.
                when('/home', {
                    templateUrl: 'EmployeeHome.aspx',
                    controller: 'EmpCtrl'
                }).
                when('/contact', {
                    templateUrl: 'ContactUs.html',
                    controller: 'EmpCtrl'
                }).
                when('/about', {
                    templateUrl: 'About.html',
                    controller: 'EmpCtrl'
                }).
                otherwise({
                    redirectTo: '/home'
                });
        }]);
```

On the  **div ng-view** it is giving errors on page inspector-

- Uncaught TypeError: window.angular.$$csp is not a function  Error:
- Unknown provider: $sceProvider <- $sce <- $route <- ngViewDirective
- Error: Circular dependency: ngViewDirective

The same code works perfectly on downloaded source file and I am unable to implement routing

Comment: You seem to have two different scripts for angular. And you also use version 1.2.26, whereas the current version is 1.5.7.

Comment: okay,I changed to latest version of both. A new problem arises by changing version. I was displaying data on table page,but now data is not showing.

Comment: Post your new HTML page. Open your console, and look for error messages.

Comment: @RiteshGupt, It could be a number of things, from your systemjs.config.js to CSP configuration since two of your errors are CSP related. Please create a Plunkr so single issues out and help further